# Get submission values from a Webform

Tags: webforms

I've got two fields in my form which are called *geographicarea* and *specialty*.

I'd like to use these values in an SQL query when the form is submitted.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you'd like to get a hold of the data before it gets inserted in the database so you can do something else with it?

If this is the case, [hook_webform_submission_presave](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_presave/7) is your friend.
The $submission object will hold the submission data. This lets you change it before it's inserted in the database or, as in your case, just do something else with it.

[Here's](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.api.php/group/webform_hooks/7) a list of all the webform hooks for D7 (with a link to D6 hooks as well if that's what you're using).